# how to simplify and find equivalent of these equivalence formulas?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

My question is about propositional logic.

**Firstly:**

*How can i simplify the formula (F≡¬F) . In my opinion this is simply false ⊥), but i'm not sure about it.*

**Secondly :**

*For the formula (p≡q) , what is the equivalent formula that contains no connectives other than  **⊃ (implication)** and **⊥ (false) ?***

Please help me! I could not find any resource on that. 
Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes :

> $\lnot \bot \equiv \top$

and thus : $(\bot \equiv \lnot \bot) \equiv \bot$.

For $p \equiv q$, we have that it is equivalent to : $(p \to q) \land (q \to p)$.

But : $(p \land q)$ is $\lnot (p \to \lnot q)$, i.e.

> $(p \to (q \to \bot)) \to \bot$.

Comment: So, the answer is ((p⊃q)⊃((q⊃p)⊃⊥))⊃⊥ , right ?

Comment: @user154335 - yes (we can check it with truth-table).

Comment: Adding that, how can i convert  **(p⊃q)** and **(p^q)**  to its equivalent formula that contains no connectives other than **≡** and **v** ?

Comment: thank you a lot ! For my question on comment, I convert (p⊃q)  expression with disjunction, but i have nothing to eleminate negation in this expression. It seems unsolvable !

Comment: @user154335 - probably because $\equiv$ and $\lor$ are not an adequate set of cnnecetives, and thus cannot express $\lnot$ ...